# Ошибка у webClient

Tags: c#

Появляется подчеркивание слова webClient в коде  на строке

```
Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(
```

И код полностью

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead("http://google.ru/");
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string html = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

И да как полученный результат вставить в lable1

Comment: WebClient **client** = new WebClient();  
Stream stream = **webClient**.OpenRead("http://google.ru/");

Comment: Эмм всё равно такая же ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример того, что Вы хотите сделать, с комментариями. Учительствовать я в общем-то могу долго, вопрос лишь в том, что это не совсем по правилам форума...

```
using System; // Здесь EventArgs и т.д. и т.п.
using System.IO; // Пространство имён, где находится System.IO.StreamReader
using System.Net; // Пространство имён, где находится System.Net.WebClient
using System.Windows.Forms; // Судя по названию, тут всё для работы с WinForms...

// Пространство имён проекта (задаётся при создании солюшена, ну и в настройках)
namespace WebClientSample
{
    // Первая форма, она же главное окно
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Конструктор класса
        // Конструктор - специализированный метод, который создаёт объект
        public Form1()
        {
            // Инициализация всего того, что лежит на форме и настраивается в дизайнере.
            // До 2008-й студии, если правильно помню, код инициализации был здесь же,
            // но потом ввели понятие partial классов. Лучше пока не углубляться в это понятие
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Событие загрузки формы.
        // Автоматически получили тыкнув на форму 2 раза.
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Новый экземпляр Веб-клиента
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            // Создаём новый поток, куда будут поступать данные
            // Конструкция using позволит грамотно закрыть поток по завершению работы с ним
            using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.ru"))
            {
                // Новый экземпляр класса, который упрощает чтение из потока
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
                // Переменная, куда считываем данные из потока
                string html = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                // Кладём полученные данные в текст Label.
                // Сам Label создаём простым перетаскиванием оного из Toolbox на форму
                label1.Text = html;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

у Вас различаются имена объекта WebClient.

```
lable1.Text = html;
```

Comment: WebClient client= new WebClient();
Stream stream = сlient.OpenRead("http://google.ru/");

Comment: Эм ни чего не поменялось. Теперь подчёркивает  client

Comment: > Теперь подчёркивает client

Вы что там курите, товарищ? Писать вроде бы умеете, читать тоже должны. Читайте, что вам IDE пишет и делайте соответствующие выводы.

Comment: Ошибка 1 Элемент "сlient" не существует в текущем контексте. \

Comment: Супер, сообщение об ошибке вы прочитали. Теперь прочитайте еще раз мой комментарий и выполните вторую часть инструкции.

Comment: Так он же существует мы присваиваем ему значение тут WebClient client = new WebClient();

Comment: @Vlmake, а Вы код прямо полностью привели? вот именно это и пытаетесь выполнить?

Answer (score 1):

А зачем у `WebClient` городить `StreamReader`?

```
public static string responseText;
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    responseText = wc.DownloadString("http://example.com");
}
```

Вот и всё - в `responseText` ответ сервиса.